# how to check if a javascript object contains null value or it itself is null

Tags: javascript

Say I'm accessing a JavaScript Object called jso in Java and I'm using the following statement to test if it's null

```
if (jso == null)
```

However, this statement seems to return true when jso contains some null values, which is not what I want.

Is there any method that can distinguish between a null JavaScript Object and a JavaScript Object that contains some null values?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean "undefined"?

Comment: Have you tried triple equals? eg '==='

Comment: @javamonkey79: Java does not have `===` it's Javascript.

Comment: @BheshGurung: I am aware of the fact that java does not have `===`, I think this might be javascript interpreted in java :P

Comment: @DaveNewton yes I mean undefined. Sorry I'm new to JavaScript

Comment: The OP wants an operator that will return true for `if ({ a: 'a', b: true, c: null } ==contains-member-with== null) ...`.  (because one of the members is null)  There is no such operator.

Comment: @user1017528 No, I think I misunderstood; I rigger you meant distinguish between a null and a variable that hasn't been set. To see if an object contains a null value you'd need to iterate over the object values or use a library that has already implemented such a function (or a function that takes a predicate function).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To determine whether the target reference contains a member with a null value, you'll have to write your own function as none exist out of the box to do this for you.  One simple approach would be:

```
function hasNull(target) {
    for (var member in target) {
        if (target[member] == null)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Needless to say, this only goes one level deep, so if one of the members on `target` contains another object with a null value, this will still return false.  As an exmaple of usage:

```
var o = { a: 'a', b: false, c: null };
document.write('Contains null: ' + hasNull(o));
```

Will print out:

> Contains null: true

In contrast, the following will print out `false`:

```
var o = { a: 'a', b: false, c: {} };
document.write('Contains null: ' + hasNull(o));
```

Answer (score 6):

This is just for your reference. Do not upvote.

```
var jso;
document.writeln(typeof(jso)); // 'undefined'
document.writeln(jso); // value of jso = 'undefined'

jso = null;
document.writeln(typeof(jso)); // null is an 'object'
document.writeln(jso); // value of jso = 'null'

document.writeln(jso == null); // true
document.writeln(jso === null); // true
document.writeln(jso == "null"); // false
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3JZfT/3/

Answer (score 2):

Try an extra `=`

```
if (jso === null)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a really wasy way to do it

```
if (Object.values(jso).includes(null)) {
    // condition
}
else{
    // condition
}
```