# Check if a js object's properties are all null except for 3

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, enumeration

I have a js object with 50 properties. I want to check if all 47 of them are null except for "a1", "a2", and "a3".

```
myObject = { 
a1: 'dont-care'
a2: 'dont-care'
a3: 'dont-care'
a4: 'am i null?'
a5: 'am i null?'
...
a50: 'am i null?'
}
```

Comment: Try this link:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936480/how-to-check-if-a-javascript-object-contains-null-value-or-it-itself-is-null][1]

Comment: Consider an *array* for an *ordered* sequence. The answers posted *require* that there is some ordering of the keys (e.g. as posted) and *will not* work in the general case as keys/properties are not ordered: if the values represent an ordered sequence then an array is almost always more appropriate. It would also be very trivial to write with `Array.slice` and `Array.every` if an array were used `x.slice(3).every(function (v) { return v !== null }` (or condition as appropriate).

Comment: @user2246674: My answer does not require any key ordering.

Comment: @CrazyTrain Hmm, I thought the question explicitly called for the "first 3" (but I guess it does not ..). Your approach is indeed flexible in this nature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys()` with `Array.prototype.every()`.

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/akstE/1/

```
var result = Object.keys(myObject)
    .every(function(key) {
        switch (key) {
            // Change these to your actual property names
            case "a1": case "a2": case "a3":
                return true; // assuming you don't need to check them at all
            default:
                return myObject[key] === null; // `== null` to include `undefined`
        }
    });
```

(Requires shims for both methods in older browsers.)

Comment: Why will this loop stop when the switch finds a false? but continue if it is true? Try adding console.log(key) to see what I mean

Comment: @DonnyP: Yes, it short circuits to end as soon as there's a failure.

Comment: So that "short circuiting" happens when we "return true"? And if it returns false, then continues on to another "every" loop?

Comment: @DonnyP: No, the `.every()` checks to see if all items pass whatever condition is given. As soon as we `return false;` it knows that not all the items met the condition, so it stops. If all items meet the given condition(s), it will have continued to the end and never received a `false` result.

Comment: No, it means `return false`. It's the nature of `every` to return `false` and stop iteration after the first non-conforming element is found. Check [the doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

Comment: @DonnyP: Here's an [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/akstE/2/) that succeeds. I changed the required property values to `null`.

Answer (score 4):

What others have said about object properties being unordered is quite true, so the concept of "first three" is meaningless.

So what you might want is a function that can be passed an object and a property name list that then checks that any property other than those in the list are `null`.

Note that I have used `=== null` so the values must really be `null`, not just `undefined`.

```
function allButThreeNull(obj, names) {
  for (var p in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p) && names.indexOf(p) == -1) {
      if (obj[p] !== null) return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

var obj = {one: 'one', two: 'two', three: 'three', four: null, fiv: null};

alert(allButThreeNull(obj, 'one two three'.split(' '))); // true
```

Note that you will need a [shim for *Array.prototype.indexOf*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) in browsers that aren't ES5 compliant (e.g. IE 8).

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
var allButFirstThreeAreNull = true;
for (var i = 4; i <= 50; i++) {
  if (myObject['a' + i] !== null) {
    allButFirstThreeAreNull = false; 
    break;
  }
}
```

The key point here is ability to address a property by some complex expression when using bracket notation (`object[property_expression]`). And, of course, you don't need to check the other properties if you found the one that's not equal to null; hence the use of `break`.

---

Now it turns out that these properties are dynamic. Well, there's one thing to do that:

```
var i, l, isValid = true, props = Object.keys(myObject);
for (i = 3, l = props.length; i < l; i++) {
  if (myObject[ props[i] ] !== null) {
    isValid = false;
    break;
  }
}
```

... except that your first three properties may actually not be the ones you think about. Check this, for example:

```
var foo = {
  '12': null,
  booya: 3
  '2': null,
  '3': null,
};
```

Logging Object.keys of that will give you `["2", "3", "12", "booya"]`, placing the numeric properties in front (and sorting them numerically).

Comment: Awesome, now is there an equivalent of "array.forEach" just for objects? Haven't been able to find one, but I vaguely remember reading one.

Comment: Actually I didn't specifiy this in the question, but my properties have actual names instead of a1 - a50. How can I access that key in this loop?

Comment: You can iterate over `Object.keys` (skipping the first three), but remember - JS objects are, strictly speaking, unordered.

Comment: You can add a condition to the loop `for ( ...; i < l && allButFirstThreeAreNull; ...)` to remove the break statement.

Comment: Argh, sorry, disregard the previous comment; thought you've talked about adding this to inner condition. Yes, it may be rewritten like that, but I actually see nothing wrong in `break` here.