# Javascript - Checking an object for null or empty key values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recently ran into a situation at work where I needed to check for null or empty keys inside an object dynamically. I looked online and saw some similar solution, but I managed to toss a function together that's pretty succinct and I was hoping to share it for whomever might benefit and get some feedback.

```
function allKeysValid(obj) {
    return !Object.keys(obj).some(key => null == obj[key] || "" === obj[key])
}
```

Hope someone can get use out of it.

Comment: I thought this was Q/A. Anyway!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question

Comment: I'd suggest rephrasing this as a question, and then adding an answer.

Comment: Well I'm sure people will do a google search for **check object for null keys** and find this sitting at the top http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936480/how-to-check-if-a-javascript-object-contains-null-value-or-it-itself-is-null#answer-7936553

Comment: @GavinRay See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291992/what-is-a-canonical-question-answer-and-what-is-their-purpose

Comment: Honestly, nice code.  Stack Overflow just really isn't the place.

Comment: Gavin, that's great stuff. However, you have to re-ask your question according to SO rules. You cannot just post an answer - but there is nothing that says you cannot ask-and-then-answer your own question. But there are already several questions on this same topic. So, my recommendation is to delete this question (before it is closed for you) and then look for the most similar question and add this as an answer. Believe me, over time your answer will be tested and (if working) upvoted.

Comment: Ahhh okay thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's like this:

```js
addEventListener('load', function(){

function completeObj(obj){
  for(var i in obj){
    var v = obj[i];
    if(!v && v !== 0){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
var objA = {a:'will fail', b:false, c:true};
var objB = {cool:'will pass', neat:0, fun:'maybe'};
var loop = [objA, objB], completes = [];
for(var i=0,o,l=loop.length; i<l; i++){
  o = loop[i];
  if(completeObj(o)){
    completes.push(o);
  }
}
console.log(completes);

});
```

Comment: I knew this has been answered before but the functions I saw posted were quite a bit more verbose. I'm not familiar enough with === to know if its behavior would have sufficed here. I didn't mean to cause a ruckus I just wanted to pass it on in case someone could use it in the future =(

Comment: I strongly recommend using `===`, and `!==` since `0` is falsey.