# Optimize nested IFELSE in TypeSript

Tags: javascript, typescript, express

Doing a personal project, I have all these conditions, I would like to know if there is a better way to do this since it does not seem to me a very clean code therefore IFELSE.

```
public static async handleLiquidations(request : Request, response: Response){
    const id = request.params.code;
    const {month, year , ...optional} = request.body;
    let msg = "";
    if(!!month && !!year ){
      const liquidationsController = new LiquidationsController();
      if(optional.amountToReport){
        liquidationsController.updateAmountToReport(month,year,optional.amountToReport);
      } else {
        msg += "missing amount to report";
      } if (optional.comments) {
        liquidationsController.updateComments();
      } else {
        msg += "missing comments";
      } if (optional.startDate) {
        liquidationsController.updateStartDate();
      } else {
        msg += "missing start date";
      } if (optional.endDate) {
        liquidationsController.updateEndDate();
      } else {
        msg += "missing end date";
      }

      response.status(200);
      response.json({optional, msg});
      return;
    } else {
      errorResponse(response,403,"Required arguments are missing")
    }
  }
```

Comment: These are no *nested* `if`/`else`s. They're indented weirdly, yes, but each `if` clause is on its own.

Comment: I just want to be sure you know that code has 4 completely independent `if/else` pairs. Because the way you have this written makes look like 8 branches of the same conditional. Other than that, there's nothing glaringly _wrong_ with this code, in my opinion. There could be ways to encapsulate this repeated pattern, but they would be more code than you have here. It's not as bad as you think it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could shorten the error messages to one single if clause:

```
if (!optional.amountToReport || !optional.comments || !optional.startDate || !optional.endDate) {
   msg = `Insufficient data: ${JSON.stringify(optional)}`;
} else {
  liquidationsController.updateAmountToReport(month,year,optional.amountToReport);
    liquidationsController.updateComments();
    liquidationsController.updateStartDate();
    liquidationsController.updateEndDate();
}
```

This will shorten your `if` clauses.

You could also write a function to determine if the optional object has `null` values in. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7936553/10817159) for more info.